# Pandas filter and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(['Air type:1', 'Space kind:2', 'water', np.NaN], columns = ['A'])

      A
0   Air type:1
1   Space kind:2
2   water
3   NaN
```

I would like to split the entries in A that have a ":" in them into two new columns. I therefore try to combine this operation with a .loc filter:

```
df.loc[(df.A.str.contains(':')) & (~df.A.isnull()), ['B', 'C']] = df.A.str.split(':', expand = True)
```

The results are not very promising though:

```
     A            B       C
0   Air type:1   NaN    NaN
1   Space kind:2 NaN    NaN
2   water        NaN    NaN
3   NaN          NaN    NaN
```

It works if I do not filter:

```
df[['B', 'C']] = df.A.str.split(':', expand = True)

           A           B        C
0   Air type:1      Air type    1
1   Space kind:2    Space kind  2
2   water             water    None
3   NaN                NaN     NaN
```

The issue is that the `water` entry gets wrongly allocated to the new columns and I have to fix it manually afterwards.

Why does the `.loc` + assign not work?

Ideally I would like to get:

```
           A           B        C
0   Air type:1      Air type    1
1   Space kind:2    Space kind  2
2   water              NaN     NaN
3   NaN                NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a condition for checking  with `df.where`:

```
c  = c = df['A'].str.contains(":")
#c = df['A'].str.count(":").ge(1)
df[['B', 'C']] = df['A'].str.split(":",expand=True).where(c)
```

---

```
print(df)
              A           B    C
0    Air type:1    Air type    1
1  Space kind:2  Space kind    2
2         water         NaN  NaN
3           NaN         NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. Would you have any idea why the `.loc` construction does not work?

Comment: @User2321 In my pandas version, tat loc construction throws a keyerror unfortunately. `KeyError: "None of [Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: honestly, I think it should work as i thought `.loc` assigned via the index. might be worth throwing up a repl and stepping through a debugger to see what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Cant reproduce since loc only works for assigning a series in my version, but not a dataframe, not sure if anything has changed in the later versions

Answer (score 3):

Another version, using `.extract()`:

```
df[["B", "C"]] = df["A"].str.extract(r"([^:]+):(.*)")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
              A           B    C
0    Air type:1    Air type    1
1  Space kind:2  Space kind    2
2         water         NaN  NaN
3           NaN         NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method using `.stack()` & `.join`

```
df1 = df.join(

  df.loc[df['A'].str.contains(':')==True]\
              .stack()\
              .str.split(':',expand=True).unstack(1).droplevel(1,1)
)
```

---

```
              A           0    1
0    Air type:1    Air type    1
1  Space kind:2  Space kind    2
2         water         NaN  NaN
3           NaN         NaN  NaN
```

---

or direct assignment.

```
df[['B','C']] = df.loc[df['A'].str.contains(':')==True]\
                              .stack()\
                              .str.split(':',expand=True)\
                              .unstack(1).droplevel(1,1)

              A           B    C
0    Air type:1    Air type    1
1  Space kind:2  Space kind    2
2         water         NaN  NaN
3           NaN         NaN  NaN
```